# How do you find the file that Avast Anti Virus is blocking connections from? (notification window doesn't give full path)

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus, avast

Avast keeps going off and popping up saying `C:\...\Update.exe` has been blocked but doesn't give me any more information. How do I find out what file is being detected and what connection is being blocked? Under the "antivirus" there isn't even a section for logs and under "firewall" I go to logs but there aren't any log entries for today.

Here's a screen shot
[image: screen shot of stupid AV message]

If I click on new details it takes me to [this webpage](http://www.avast.com/en-us/lp-pr-virus-alert?p_ext=&utm_campaign=Virus_alert&utm_source=prg_ise_90_0&utm_medium=prg_systray&utm_content=./paid/en-us/virus-alert-default&p_vir=URL:Mal&p_prc=C:%5CUsers%5CJosh%5CAppData%5CLocal%5CSwvUpdater%5CUpdater.exe&p_obj=http://www.giganticdownload.com/update.php&p_var=./paid/en-us/virus-alert-default&p_elm=7&p_lex=13277&p_lid=en-us&p_lng=en&p_lqa=3&p_lqe=1&p_lst=0&p_lsu=24&p_pro=2&p_vep=9&p_ves=0&p_vbd=2007&p_hid=d648e841-f16f-4657-8a0c-46ca8568f1b1) owned by Avast.

Comment: "How do I find out what file is being detected" -- I'm a little confused by this request, as it tells you the path to find it, and the program name, right there (update.exe)?

Comment: @techie007 no no, it literally just puts ...

Comment: What do you see if you click on "More details..."?

Comment: @cmorse I can't try it right now as the pop up isn't up but more details takes me to a website that just talks about new virus trends.

Comment: Have you tried searching system for Updater.exe? I don't think there would be many of them, especially in Users directory.

Answer (score 1):

**First**, Do not turn off your AV protection just for the sake of not getting the alerts. It is definitely for your long term good.

However, try to recognize to which software that the **Updater.exe** belongs and remove it if it is harmful or unknown.

**Main problem with the updaters** : They can download files in your computer and install automatically without your permission if you have left the Update automatically option during the installation of the software. If a Trojan program is installed in your system, then it is no longer called "your system" in the security circle.

By reading through the link you have given in your question, i see that **URL:Mal** could be the culprit that is trying to harm your system.

If one of the software that you installed is trying to access a **malicious website or vicious URL** then the AV comes into action by detecting it as a kind of virus infection.

It is important to pay attention to this issue or else your **web browser** might get affected. Then there will be a lot of stuff will happen to your browser (like unknown add-ons, tool bars, unwanted ads,etc.,) and your AV will detect even the normal websites you visit as harmful once your browser is infected.

Now all you have to do is just to confirm whether the detected **Updater.exe** is harmful and carry on with the **removal** process(I found [Remove URL:Mal](http://blog.mightyuninstaller.com/remove-urlmal-how-to-get-rid-of-urlmal-completely/) and [Removal Mal](http://removevirusinfections.blogspot.in/2013/08/urlmal-removal-instructions-how-to-get.html) articles that gives a walk through on the removal of URL:Mal infectors). If you are not sure about the existence of such malwares in your system there are plenty of ways to sweep them off using a good **anti-malware** with an **updated anti-virus software**.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar problem with other antivirus software. It's aggravating when antivirus software reports a problem with a file but displays "..." or something similar as part of the directory path and lacks an easy way to see the full directory path, especially when there may be many files with the name noted on the system. The developers of such antivirus software often seem to assume that the users of their product are technically unsophisticated and so just want to click on a "remove" button. Such alerts should at least be logged in a file by an entry containing the full path and file name with the log file easily viewed by a user.

To resolve the problem you could install additional anti-malware software and scan the system with it. I've found [Malwarebytes Anti-Malware](https://www.malwarebytes.org) works well with antivirus software from other vendors. You can download the free version and scan the system with it. It may also flag a updater.exe file. Alternatively, you could search the system for every updater.exe file and upload them one by one to [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com), a site now owned by Google that will scan files you upload with many antivirus programs and display a report letting you know how many of them detected a file as malware and the name assigned by each to the malware, if they identify the file as being associated with malware. Other sites that will also scan an uploaded file with multiple antivirus programs:

[Jotti's malware scan](http://virusscan.jotti.org/).

[VirSCAN.org](http://virscan.org/)